# Two devices cannot ping each other through WiFi

Tags: wireless-networking, ping

I have WiFi router connected to the Internet through pppoe. Router has latest version of firmware installed. I have no any antivirus software running and firewall enabled.

My router is an [ASUS RT-N10LX](http://www.asus.com/Networking/RTN10LX/).

```
My net is   : 192.168.1.0/24  
WiFi gateway: 192.168.1.1  
WiFi clients: 192.168.1.2(OS Windows 7 Professional (x32)),  
              192.168.1.3(Android 4.xx)
```

I have access to the Internet from any connected devices. I can ping WiFi router from any devices which have wireless connection to it. From webadmin of my WiFi router, I can see IP addresses of all devices connected to it.

**I cannot do ping between devices.**
I have "Destination Host Unreachable" message.

But I can do ping from my PC if it connected by cable.

I already did:

```
  i)netsh int ip reset resetlog.txt  
 ii)netsh winsock reset catalog 
iii)netsh -c interface ipv4 add neighbors "Network Card Name" "192.168.1.3" "xx-xx-xx-xx"
```

What do I need to do to resolve this?

Comment: Can you ping the devices from your router? Many routers offer a ping test tool via webinterface. Also do you have another windows/linux client to test with as this would be easier to debug. Also please include output from `ipconfig /all` as well as a `route print`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many wireless access points have "client isolation" enabled, which prohibits direct communication between connected devices. It's likely you just need to disable that.

Comment: I've already checked my access point for 'client isolation'. It's disabled.

Comment: My router doesn't have the "client isolation" setting, so I tried disabling the firewall instead and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for that, it is in Wireless -> Professional menu as "Set AP Isolated" and I had to set it to "Yes" and "Apply" and then back to "No" and "Apply" and now it works.

Comment: That presumably depends on the exact device involved.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. I've done factory reset for my router and issue was solved.
Thanks to all for helping.

Comment: Issue was worked around, not solved.