# Wifi connected PC doesn't show up in Network window

Tags: networking, windows-8.1

I have set up a makeshift LAN at my place with one wifi router and a switch and connected with 5 PCs and 3 mobile devices and a wifi enabled laptops. All PCs are connected with the switch, while the Wireless devices are directly connected to the router using wifi.

Now the problem is my wireless connections doesn't show up in Network in my wired LAN. I can't even see them in IP messenger, while all other PCs appears properly.

All of my wired PC and Wifi enabled laptop has Windows 8.1. How can I make my laptop to appear on the Network places in the desktops?

Let me know if you need any more details on this.
Thanks

**Update**:- I didn't turned on File sharing on my PC which I just did and now I can see my laptop on my PC, but I can't see my pC on my laptop. I can see similar issue in ip messenger. I can see my laptop in ipmsgr but can't see my pc from my laptop.

Comment: Is the "Find devices and content" switched on within the laptop's settings? - [Find PCs, devices, and content on your network](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/find-pcs-devices-content-on-network)

Comment: Both computers are set to discovery other devices on the network, and both devices are set so they can be discovered, and both are using the same version of Windows?

Comment: @CharlieRB Yeah Find Devices and content is switched on to all devices, including the laptop.

Comment: @Ramhound Yeah the version of windows is almost same. My laptop has windows 8.1 pro x64 edition, while the PCs have Windows 8.1 Pro N x64 edition. All of them are set to discover other devices and are discoverable.

Comment: its more to do with your routers settings.
http://superuser.com/questions/605336/two-devices-cannot-ping-each-other-through-wifi

Check this out.